# opus_encoder_create() return a null pointer

Tags: c++, c, codec

Im having some trouble with opus-codec.

opus_encoder_create() return a null pointer and throw an OPUS_BAD_ARG error

```
OpusEncoder * m_enc;
m_enc = opus_encoder_create(44100, 2, OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP, &this->m_error);
```

this is what I get with gdb:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000001fa4
opus_encode_float (st=0x0, pcm=0x100717e20, frame_size=8, data=0x100840c00 "", out_data_bytes=4000) at opus_encoder.c:581
581     st->rangeFinal = 0;
(gdb) bt
#0  opus_encode_float (st=0x0, pcm=0x100717e20, frame_size=8, data=0x100840c00 "", out_data_bytes=4000) at opus_encoder.c:581
#1  0x0000000100002b1d in Encoder::Encode (this=0x7fff5fbffa70, audioFrame=0x100717e20, frameSize=8) at Encoder.cpp:39
#2  0x000000010000192c in main () at main.cpp:101
```

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/group__opus__encoder.html#gaa89264fd93c9da70362a0c9b96b9ca88) lists the supported sampling frequencies:

> This must be one of 8000, 12000, 16000, 24000, or 48000.

Notice that 44100 is not in the list; that would seem excellent cause for a "bad argument" error.